# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "pma-springbootdb"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I am working on my first sprinboot application, Where am trying to configure the properties for postgreSQL Database in my sprinboot application. When i run this application i am getting following error.

```
**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "pma-springbootdb" does not exist**
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readStartupMessages(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2645) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.<init>(QueryExecutorImpl.java:138) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:255) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jd
......
2020-06-03 09:33:13.052  WARN 1225 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : FATAL: database "pma-springbootdb" does not exist
2020-06-03 09:33:13.078  WARN 1225 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : **Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:** Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is **org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate** 
**Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'** defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed   : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2020-06-03 09:33:13.079  INFO 1225 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-06-03 09:33:13.084  INFO 1225 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-06-03 09:33:13.112  INFO 1225 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener 
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:** Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository' defined in com.jrp.pma.dao.EmployeeRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext'
```

- *PostgreSQL properties*

  spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pma-springbootdb

  ```
  spring.datasource.username=***

  spring.datasource.password=***

  spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never

  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true

  spring.jpa.show-sql=true
  spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
  version=3.0.0
  ```
- *SQL Query*

  CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS employee_seq;

  ```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (

  employee_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('employee_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  first_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL

  );

  CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS project_seq;

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project (

  project_id BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('project_seq') PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  stage VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL

  );


  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS project_employee (

  project_id BIGINT REFERENCES project, 
  employee_id BIGINT REFERENCES employee

  );
  ```
- *Project.java*

  ```
   @Entity
      public class Project {

  @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "project_seq")

  private Long projectId;
      ....
      ....
       }
  ```

  *

  - *Employee.java*

  *

  ```
  @Entity
  public class Employee {
  @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_seq")
      private long employeeId;
  ...
  ..
  }
  ```

[image: PostgreSQL Database Strucutre]

[image: port]

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. If you have a different problem after fixing your typo, please ask a new question. Don't change your question to something completely different. You can delete this question, because it was simply caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1):

The message `database "pma-springbootdb" does not exist` is self-explanatory.

This database does not exist in the PostgreSQL instance running on `localhost` with port 5432. Either it's a wrong database name or it's the wrong instance.

Please doublecheck: pma-springboot**db** vs pma-springboot**bd**

Comment: I have added a screen shot of postgreSQL database in which it shows pma-springbootdb. I think that is not the problem.

Comment: Are you really sure that this instance runs on `localhost` with port 5432 ? Please post output of `show listen_addresses; show port;\l` (to be run with `psql` CLI).

Comment: Thank you i made a spelling mistake. Even after correcting the file name, i am getting "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:"

Comment: Please doublecheck in Java code you have `pma-springbootdb` in PostgreSQL you have `pma-springbootbd`. `db` is different from `bd`

Comment: @npr: both screenshots clearly show the database  is named `pma-springbootbd` but your JDBS URL uses `pma-springbootdb`  (**bd** vs **db** at the end)

Comment: If you have another error message, please ask another question with full error message.